# Sitecore XP 10.3.1, Sitecore Headless Services Server XP 21.0.587, International phone number Form field (intlTelInput)

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms

I want to create a International phone number field that allows user to select the country code and then enter the number. Country selection is a dropdown with Country flag, country code, and an arrow icon. I want to achieve this using Sitecore JSS form.

[image: International Number dropdown]

---

Team created a custom form input field for the form.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html